# Connect expo based React Native app to local REST API server during development

Tags: react-native, networking, expo

I'm building a simple React Native app (using expo) that needs to connect to a REST API Server.

In production, the REST API will just be a regular web URL, but for convenience during development I'd like to be able to connect to the same server that is being used to host the local expo server, i.e. the server on which I run `npm run android`. This is currently a local IP address like `10.2.2.45` but might change.

Is there a way to get the IP address of this local sever automatically from within the React Native app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Working with expo 48.0.18 and react-native 0.71.8

The easiest way I found was to use `expo-constants` module and then retrieve the `manifest` where expo app stores the device ip address of the expo app host.

```js
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
const { manifest } = Constants;

const [host] = manifest.debuggerHost.split(':'); // Get host of expo app and remove the port
host.concat(':YOUR_PORT') // Add your port
```

A simple implementation for your app would be something like this

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
const { manifest } = Constants;

const [address, setAddress] = useState("")

useEffect(() => {
    const getServerIPAddress = async () => {
        if (manifest.packagerOpts.dev) { // Check if app is in development mode
            console.log(manifest)
            const [host] = manifest.debuggerHost.split(':'); // Get host of expo app and remove the port
            setAddress(host.concat(':YOUR_PORT')); // Add your port
        } else {
            setAddress('api.example.com'); // Address for production
        }
    };
    getServerIPAddress();
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
        const f = await fetch(`http://${address}/api`);
        const response = await f.json();
        console.log(response) // Hello World
    }
    getData();
}, [address])
```

Comment: Thanks! Seems to work well for me, in the simple cases at least